# Why does Javascript only count carriage returns as one character when it is two?

Tags: javascript, dom, carriage-return

This is an offshoot of this question: [Chrome counts characters wrong in textarea with maxlength attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10030921/561731)

---

In that question it was found that [Javascript counts carriage returns are one character when in fact it is two (`\r\n`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030992/561731), why is that?

Test Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/E527z/

Comment: Here's your answer with evidence: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#concept-textarea-api-value

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For reasons unknown, jQuery always converts all newlines in the value of a `<textarea>` to a single character. That is, if the browser gives it `\r\n` for a newline, jQuery makes sure it's just `\n` in the return value of `.val()`. (Actually the reason probably isn't "unknown"; it's probably to normalize the results across browsers, because IE reports newlines as being 2 characters long.)

Chrome and Firefox both count the length of `<textarea>` tags the same way for the purposes of "maxlength".

However, the HTTP spec insists that newlines be represented as `\r\n`.  Thus, jQuery, webkit, and Firefox all get this wrong. When the field is posted, webkit and Firefox correctly add the newlines!

The upshot is that "maxlength" on `<textarea>` tags is pretty much useless if your server-side code really has a fixed maximum size for a field value.

**Edit** This is still an issue in 2015 - at least on Chrome 45.0.2454 and IE 11.0.9600.

Comment: "The upshot is that "maxlength" on <textarea> tags is pretty much useless if your server-side code really has a fixed maximum size for a field value." I'm confused. It seems to me you are saying jQuery reports newlines as a single character, but the browser correctly uses two characters. If this is the case, wouldn't the `maxlength` attribute actually work correctly and count newlines as two characters, which is how the data will be saved on the backend?

Comment: @wired_in no, because the browser maintainers are weird people and they don't seem to understand the whole point of `maxlength` (my personal opinion).  I've logged bugs against Firefox and WebKit and the amount of bizarre uninformed pushback I've gotten is amazing. The `maxlength` implementations check the length as returned by `.value`, which is to say the length *without* the CR characters that are introduced when the form is posted. I've moved on and I'll just stick with my JavaScript solution.

Comment: "The `maxlength` implementations check the length as returned by `.value`, which is to say the length without the CR characters" - It's the other way round. `maxlength` counts the CR+LF (which JavaScript does not) - as demonstrated by the above jsfiddle and in the linked question. So, `maxlength` is actually correct with respect to server-side code, it's only a "problem" if you are also processing this with client-side JavaScript.

Comment: @w3d things may be different now since the last time I tested this, but in the past it was definitely the case that (other than IE, oddly) browsers reported the value without the carriage returns, and that was what the `maxlength` thing checked - there's extensive discussion in bugs I logged back then with both Mozilla and the WebKit people.

Comment: @w3d yes Firefox and Chrome both seem to do this correctly now.

Comment: @w3d wait, I take that back - see [this extremely simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpfe4n1y/). Type stuff, including hard returns, and see how many characters Firefox lets you type. Firefox 40.0.3 is clearly treating hard returns as 1 character, not 2.

Comment: Confirmed: Chrome (current: 47.0.2526.111, and Canary: v50.0.2525.0) still includes `\r` and `\n` when considering `maxlength`, and this appears to actually help with HTTP standard to POST newlines as `\r\n` (browser input matches server). FireFox and Internet explorer (10 and up, where HTML5 `textarea maxlength` support was introduced) do not consider `\r` when enforcing `maxlength` and in their case the problem is that if the server is following same rules to truncate data (which is good idea when sanitizing inputs because `maxlength` is easy to bypass) then the server input does not match.

Comment: I've updated the JS fiddle to update faster/on-the-fly as you type http://jsfiddle.net/E527z/35/ but I don't see any browser treating textarea linebreaks as 2 characters (`\r` + `\n`) in JavaScript or when applying the `maxlength` attribute (including Chrome up to 65/67)... when submitting to the server, the linebreaks are "doubled" as `\r\n` as expected by the specs.

Comment: @scunliffe I gave up trying to get either Chrome or FF devs to understand the issue; in some ways it's broken all the way back to the spec, because ultimately the devs (both groups) ended up waving some spec around.

Comment: @Pointy I'm in the camp that a single `\n` in the browser world is fine, and that all backend solutions need to coerce `\r\n` into `\n` *if* that is what the backend/DB desires. Certain parts of the history of the web baffle me. I get the `/` vs. \ Unix vs. Microsoft war in the URL path... but IMHO, the `\r\n` was a mistake.

Comment: @scunliffe I don't understand why the `\r` is mandated either, so getting rid of that would be fine too. It's just a weird situation.

Comment: "For reasons unknown" - this post seems to go some way to explaining: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/2101#issuecomment-344771526

Comment: @gb2d thanks but I gave up arguing with the pedants who clearly have never actually implemented a real web application a long time ago :)