# Return key in textarea counts as 2 characters for chrome

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea maxlength="10"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I am encountering an issue that counts return key as 2 characters. I have applied regex also to solve this issue but unable to do that. 
The regex I applied is (/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\n')

Comment: Length of the text in the textarea

Comment: Do you need to count all characters of textarea ?

Comment: Is the count different after the regex? would a simple string replace give different result?

Comment: yeah i need to count all characters including return key

Comment: This simple string is replacing and the count is updated perfectly. But I don't want to omit return key. I want return key to be there in the model but the count for that should be 1 and not 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carriage returns in Chrome are `\r\n`, which are considered two characters (`\r` and `\n`).

I would recommend you to take a look in the following questions:

- [Chrome counts characters wrong in textarea with maxlength attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute)
- [Get the character count of a textarea including newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924591/get-the-character-count-of-a-textarea-including-newlines)
- [Why does Javascript only count carriage returns as one character when it is two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031112/why-does-javascript-only-count-carriage-returns-are-one-character-when-it-is-two)

The last link can provide an explanation as why limiting the length by HTML attributes make the new line count as two characters (which is the real length) while JavaScript code considers them to be a single character.

If you really need to worry about line breaks and character counting, I would suggest you to replace the length validation in HTML by a JavaScript validation in your AngularJS application, as you would be able to count line breaks as a single character, as desired.