# Issue with text-area in chrome browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

I have `textarea` with `maxlength` attribute i.e. `maxlength="20"`. After entering 10 ENTER keys it stops entering any characters while maxlength is 20 in **CHROME BROWSER**. If you want to test this issue then open [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SandeepDixit/zQqV9/) and hit ENTER key 10 times.

```
<textarea row="10" cols="10" maxlength="20"></textarea>
```

**Note:** Enter characters with ENTER key and see.

Comment: Why does the linked fiddle has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: If I try `<textarea row="10" cols="10" maxlength="20"></textarea>` in Chromium it let me enter 20 chars. Opera doesn't respect this attribute.

Comment: If you hit ENTER key then it allow you to hit ENTER key only 10 times in Google chrome.

Comment: This Question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the **EnterKey** is considered to return two characters i.e **"\r\n".**

Thats the reason you are only able to press **10 times since the maxlength is 20.**

Added:
If you want use Jquery to resolve this :

```
var text = $('#textbox').val();

text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"");
```

Comment: but when you see character length, it display only 10

Comment: the HTTP specification insists that the newlines be represented as \r\n which takes up 2 characters.

Comment: So, how to overcome this issue, how to make jquery to count it as 2 chars.