# jQuery textarea counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I have this `jQuery` code

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('document').ready(function () {
        var text_max = "5000";
        $('#ram').html(text_max + '/5000');

        window.setInterval(function () {
            $("#post").attr("maxlength", "5000");
            var text_length = $('#post').val().length;
            var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
            if ($("#post").val().length < 4750) {
                $('#ram').html('<abbr title="You Have ' + text_remaining + ' Characters Remaining In This Post" style="visibility: hidden;">' + text_remaining + '/5000</abbr>');
            } else {
                $('#ram').html('<abbr title="You Have ' + text_remaining + ' Characters Remaining In This Post">' + text_remaining + '/5000</abbr>');
            }
            if ($("#post").val().length <= 5000) {
                $("#subm").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $("#subm").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            if ($("#post").val().length < 4980) {
                $("#ram").removeAttr("style");
            } else {
                $("#ram").attr("style", "color:#ff0000;");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And My `HTML`:

```
<form action='posting' method='POST'><center><font color='#ff0000' style='style=font-family: Sarala, sans-serif;display: inline-block;word-break: break-word;'></font><br><table><tr><td><textarea rows='15' cols='40' style='resize: none;max-width: 297px;max-height: 225px;width: 297px;height: 225px;' name='post' id='post' maxlength='5000' spellcheck='true' autofocus></textarea></center></td></tr><tr><td><div class='ram' id='ram' name='ram'><noscript><center>There Is A 500 Character Limit On All Posts</center></noscript></div></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><center><input type='submit' value='Post&#33;' class='subm' id='subm' name='subm'></center></td></tr></table></form>
```

However I want it to account the appropriate value of the textarea, however this is because when you press `enter` it accounts it as `2` instead of `1`. What I need to do is to get the value to an equal amount opposed to an unequal amount. Is there any way of doing this, with the code below. Or would I completely need to redo it, if so I am not good at `jQuery` or `Javascript`; so I will need your help??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you want the code to accept an enter as a character?

Comment: @Mashpoe Yes, Just as one character. but for me it comes up as two???

Comment: can you please show your html?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome counts characters wrong in textarea with maxlength attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute)

Comment: @Mashpoe my html is now on my post!

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924591/

Comment: On Chrome vesrion 49.0.2623.108 m the bug does not exist any more.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle from that question that correctly counts the characters: http://jsfiddle.net/Qw6vz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are a few things here.

First of all; you can use the [`keyUp`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event (although it's beter to use the [`.on('keyup', handler)`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) variant). Because as of now you're just looping endlessly, while you don't want to check everytime if the user didn't do anything, right?

Furthermore; the `jQuery(document).ready();` callback is more then enough, you don't need to wrap it in the `jQuery(window).load()` callback.

Then I would just add/remove classes as appropriate. It makes it a lot easier to maintain. As a rule of the thumb, you don't want to add styling in your scripts. That's what css is for.

I think this little script does what you want. Checkout the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gqvne88q/) here.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Calculate remaining characters
    function charactersRemaining() {
        var charactersAllowed = $('input[name="characters-allowed"]').val();
        return {
            allowed: charactersAllowed,
            remaining: charactersAllowed - $('textarea[name="post"]').val().length
        };
    };

    // Do stuff when calculated the characters
    function updateCharacterCount() {

    var characterCount = charactersRemaining();

    // Update notifiers
    $('.characters-remaining').text(characterCount.remaining);
    $('.allowed-characters').text(characterCount.allowed);

    // Update properties and classes
    if( characterCount.remaining < 0 ) {
        $('button.submit').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('button.submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }

    if( characterCount.remaining <= 0 ) {
        $('.character-count').addClass('overflow');
      $('textarea[name="post"]').addClass('limit');
    } else {
        $('.character-count').removeClass('overflow');
      $('textarea[name="post"]').removeClass('limit');
    }
  };

  // Register events for form fields
  $('textarea[name="post"], input[name="characters-allowed"]').on('keyup', function() {
    updateCharacterCount();
  });

  // As a little extra disallow typing of extra characters
  $('body').on('keydown', 'textarea[name="post"].limit', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if( keyCode !== 8 && keyCode !== 46 ) { // allow backspace and delete button
        e.preventDefault();
    }

  });

  // initialize
  updateCharacterCount();

});
```

Please note; as of now typing is limited, *and* the post button is disabled whenever characters do overflow. This sounds stupid, but you can still paste more then allowed characters. You could build in a function that strips off extra characters. But I was too lazy for that. You can also transform this into a plugin if you'd like. But I was also too lazy for that ;)

Comment: Could you please explain about how it works as I might want to make a few changes

Comment: This also breaks on high order unicode and multi-byte characters where a character doesn't fit into USC2/UTF16.

Comment: Not sure but using onchange might solve the paste issue.

Comment: @antipanchi it's all quite straightforward, checkout the jQuery api docs for explanation of used functions like `prop()`  and `on()`. But basically I did three things; first I built a function to calculate how many characters are left. Second I built a function to change the DOM whenever needed (add/remove css classes and text in the notifiers to visually tell the user what's going on). And third I attached events to the textarea and the allowed characters input field which fires the function that changes the DOM if needed. And a little bonus to prevent the user to write extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious because on my computer I cannot repeat your problem. Could you test my snippet?

```js
$(function () {
  var text_max = 5000;
  $("#post").attr("maxlength", text_max);
  $('#ram').html('<abbr title="You Have ' + text_max + ' Characters Remaining In This Post">' + text_max + '/5000</abbr>');

  $('#post').on('keyup', function () {
    var text_length = $('#post').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    $('#ram').html('<abbr title="You Have ' + text_remaining + ' Characters Remaining In This Post">' + text_remaining + '/5000</abbr>');
    if ($("#post").val().length < 5000) {
      $("#subm").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
      $("#subm").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    if ($("#post").val().length < 4980) {
      $("#ram").removeAttr("style");
    } else {
      $("#ram").attr("style", "color:#ff0000;");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<form action='posting' method='POST'>
    <center><font color='#ff0000'
                  style='style=font-family: Sarala, sans-serif;display: inline-block;word-break: break-word;'></font><br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea rows='15' cols='40'
                              style='resize: none;max-width: 297px;max-height: 225px;width: 297px;height: 225px;'
                              name='post' id='post' maxlength='5000' spellcheck='true' autofocus></textarea>
    </center>
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='ram' id='ram' name='ram'>
                <noscript>
                    <center>There Is A 500 Character Limit On All Posts</center>
                </noscript>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <center><input type='submit' value='Post&#33;' class='subm' id='subm' name='subm'></center>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```