# how to display how many characters left for textarea like in twitter?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

this is my code

```
<h3>Comment</h3>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Your Comment" maxlength="300" required/></textarea>
```

And I want to display how many characters left like in twitter with JavaScript only ! 
is there some way ?
I know nothing in javascript !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count textarea characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086398/count-textarea-characters)

Comment: I know nothing in javascript !

Comment: You have to learn some basic JavaScript then!

Comment: Yes  !
I'm willing to ! 
Now I;m learning php !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var letterLimit = 150; 
var textarea = document.getElementById("comment");

document.getElementById("lettersCount").innerHTML  = letterLimit;

textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById("lettersCount").innerHTML = letterLimit - textarea.value.length;
}, false);
```

```html
<h3>Comment</h3>
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Your Comment" maxlength="300" required/></textarea>
<div id="lettersCount"></div>
```