# Check textarea maxlength

Tags: javascript, textarea

i need check my textarea maxlength of character. But i need check that by javascript. This is my code

```
<script>
  function checkform(form) {
   if(document.filter.myarea.value.length > 255) {
     alert("Maxlength is 255!");
     return false;
    }
     return true; 
 }  
</script>
<form method="post" name="filter" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
 <textarea name="myarea">Some text</textarea>
</form>
```

Why this isn t working ? thank you

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086398/count-textarea-characters

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function checkform(form) {
   if(document.filter.myarea.value.length > 255) {
     alert("Maxlength is 255!");
     return false;
    }
     return true; 
 }  
</script>
<form method="post" name="filter" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
 <textarea name="myarea" id="myarea">Some text</textarea>
</form>
```

add id attribute to area should work.