# how do i use jquery to count the charecter left in a text box on asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net core 2 to create a form, i want to count the number of characters left when the user is typing but its not working, so on the view i have tried this

```
<div id="counter" class="error"></div>
@Html.TextArea("Text2", new { @id = "Text2" })
```

and this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MaxLength.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
        //Specifying the Character Count control explicitly.
        $("#Text2").MaxLength(
            {
                MaxLength: 15,
                CharacterCountControl: $('#counter')
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Specify `MaxLength.min.js`, but not minifed

Comment: Check this linke. [Max Lenth](http://6edesign.github.io/maxLength/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to subtract the textarea length from 15.

See [Count textarea characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086398/count-textarea-characters) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include all related css and script?

I reproduce a demo about your MaxLength library. It work well.

```js
 $(function () {
        //Normal Configuration.
        $("#TextBox1").MaxLength({ MaxLength: 10 });
 
        //Specifying the Character Count control explicitly.
        $("#TextBox2").MaxLength(
        {
            MaxLength: 15,
            CharacterCountControl: $('#counter')
        });
 
        //Disable Character Count.
        $("#TextBox3").MaxLength(
        {
            MaxLength: 20,
            DisplayCharacterCount: false
        });
    });
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src='https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript"  src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/2649/MaxLength.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.24/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<input type="text" id="TextBox1" style="width: 300px" value = "Mudassar Khan" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="counter" style="color:red;font-weight:bold"></div>
<input type="text" id="TextBox2" style="width: 300px" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" id="TextBox3" style="width: 300px" />
```