# Jquery word counts when user type line break

Tags: jquery

I have a word counts create in jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/DqYsN/

However if user press 'Enter'(line break), it will cause 1 character left.

ex.`maxlength=10`, if user type **abcde**, **\n**, **abc**

total become 9 characters only and the `div` show 1 character left

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //Word Count
        $('.word_count')
        .on('input keyup keydown focus', function () {
            var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
            var value = $(this).val();

            if(value.length > 0) {
                $(this).nextAll('div').first().text((maxlength - $(this).val().length));
            } else {
                $(this).nextAll('div').first().text(maxlength);
            }   
        }); 
});
```

i just find out Chrome count characters wrong in textarea

[Chrome counts characters wrong in textarea with maxlength attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/chrome-counts-characters-wrong-in-textarea-with-maxlength-attribute)

Comment: What is precisely the expected behavior?

Comment: Side note, you might also want to catch 'paste'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome count line break as 2 characters, put this one inside of your code should be fine.

```
var isChrome = window.chrome;
if(isChrome){var value = $(this).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"  ");}
else{ var value = $(this).val();}
```

`"  "` this make length 2 characters, so it will match with textarea length in chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can find the exact character length like this (*excluding any space and line breaks*)

```
var length = $.trim($(this).val()).split(" ").join("").split('\n').join('').length;
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/DqYsN/1/

Comment: Why again we used join here?

Comment: @PSR, To remove `space` between words

Comment: maxlength="10" will still count if u press any key, so if max - lenght, it will still have problem. because Im using count down

Comment: You should not return false when backspace was hit tbh

Comment: I just find out maxlength, \n occupied 2 characters length

Comment: @ChrisS. , Yes ! i didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the whitespaces before counting with something like: `.replace(/\s/,'')`

So instead of:

```
$(this).val().length)
```

You do:

```
$(this).val().replace(/\s/,'').length)
```