# count string length including 'invisible characters' like \r \n in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5.1, string-length

I am trying to display a "x characters left" text next to a textarea, to see how much still can be written, with javascript / jquery:

```
var area = 'textarea#zoomcomment';
var c = $(area).val().length;
```

Then the input is validated with laravel's `max` validation.

```
'comment' => 'required|max:3000'
```

The javascript does not count the `\n` or `\r` characters, but PHP/laravel does. Is there a javascript function to count everything , including linebreaks etc ? I'd like to have the same string length with js and php.

### edit:

it seems, that javascript/jquery counts `\n\r` as `1` and php `strlen()` counts it as `2` characters. I tried to avoid jquery, but it still seemed to count wrong :(

```
        var c = document.getElementById('zoomcomment').value.length;
        alert(c);
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030921/) has a good answer

Comment: Are you sure the `\n` and `\r` characters are not being counted? [It seems to be working fine on Firefox at least.](http://jsfiddle.net/vcny46hd/)

Comment: ok. yes it seems to count right, when typing, i see... but when i copypaste a 3000 character text from http://www.loremipsum.de/, my js counting function says 3000 characters and php strlen() says 3010. something seems to be wrong

Comment: i did not see the fiddle, sorry. it alerts with firefox but not in chromium, here

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using html function which gives you innerhtml  -

```
var area = 'textarea#zoomcomment';
var c = $(area).html().length;
```